# What is the control that I use on Mac OSX apps that is similar to UITableView on iOS?

Tags: ios, macos

I am trying to display a list of items in a Mac application and wondering what is the closest match to UITableView on Mac.Is it NSTableView?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll probably want one of `NSTableView`, `NSOutlineView` (deals with hierarchical data), or `NSCollectionView` (bindings only).

If you’re willing to consider third party controls, [Cocoa Objects](http://cocoaobjects.com/) lists some alternative controls for tabular views.